# Anaconda on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, anaconda

**Anaconda** was successfully installed using  [Example 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-data-science-environment-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-c4b390803dd) in my **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)**.

After completing the installation, I managed to run a Jupyter notebook in a browser and everything was working as expected. However, when I restart WSL, my anaconda virtual environment isn't recognised when WSL is launched. I can only access features, such as Jupyter, by executing `source ~anaconda3/bin/activate` first.

I managed to get around this by adding `source ~anaconda3/bin/activate` to my `~/.bash_profile`, but I haven't found any tutorials online that suggest this should necessary. Is this workaround acceptable, or should I be using an alternative approach, to force WSL to "remember" my anaconda virtual env?

Comment: Example 2 link seems to be dead